# Get row id from selected bwu_data_grid row

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, bwu-datagrid

I subscribe on bwu click event:

```
grid.onBwuClick.listen((e) {
  int id = grid.dataProvider.items[e.cell.row]['id'];
});
```

And I have pagination for table. 
When clicked row on first page I get right row id. But on other pages I get id of row from first page.

[image]
I expected 768 and 769 ids.

Should I do something when page changed?

Comment: Looks like a bug. I don't know though when I'll have time to investigate :-/

Comment: Cross-link https://github.com/bwu-dart/bwu_datagrid/issues/153

Comment: Maybe it can be selected like this: `var html = grid.querySelector('.bwu-datagrid .active .selected').innerHtml;` but I get:  `The null object does not have a getter 'innerHtml'.`

Comment: Sorry, no idea. I have to investigate. Or perhaps you're motivated to debug and create a pull request?

Comment: So, to save time I do it like this: `grid.onClick.listen((event) {
      Element cell = grid.getActiveCellNode();
      DivElement idCell = cell.parentNode.querySelector('.r0');

      var rowId = idCell.text;
    });`

Comment: Nice one . . . . .

Comment: maybe I can be able to find the right way later